# Making a tree with MySQL datas

Tags: json, laravel

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+------+-----------------+---------+------------+
| id   | name            | refferal| reference  |
+------+-----------------+---------+------------+
|    1 | Alex Muller     |       1 |       null |
|    2 | John Doe        |       2 |          1 |
|    3 | Tom Foe         |       3 |          1 |
|    4 | Harry Pott      |       4 |          3 |
|    5 | Kate Garry      |       5 |          3 |
|    6 | Mike Blue       |       6 |          4 |
+------+-----------------+---------+------------+
```

(more data than this...)

I need to turn that data to JSON file with Laravel. Like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Alex Muller","parent":0},
{"id":2,"name":"John Doe","parent":1},
{"id":3,"name":"Tom Foe","parent":1},
{"id":4,"name":"Harry Pott","parent":3},
{"id":5,"name":"Kate Garry","parent":3},
{"id":6,"name":"Mike Blue","parent":4}]
```

At the and of this I will get a tree view like this:

[TREE](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/tree.png)

I just made this json file with my own write. And I don't know what to do. I'm waiting your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add extra fields like "parent" in your example you can use map on the collection:

```
 $users = User::where(function($query){
  ...
 })->get()->map(function($user){
   return array(
     "id"  => $user->id,
     "name" => $user->name,
     "parent" => *INTEGER*
   );
 })->toJson();
```

Or if you just want to encode the model attributes, you can use toJson serialization directly with the collection:

```
$users = User::User::where(function($query){
  ...
 })->get()->toJson();
```

for further information, refer to the links:

https://laravel.com/docs/collections

https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json

Comment: Can i do this with child inside child ?

Comment: @hrafn Sorry, but what do you mean with child inside child? If you mean the related models then you can map them too inside your main map

Comment: I mean a nested json file.  Like `{
    1: {
        2: '',
        3: {
            6: '',
            7: '',
        },
        4: '',
        5: ''
    }
}`

Comment: My main problem is how do I get the data from the database connected like this. I want to get all the users under the user because they are linked. So it's like a family tree.

Comment: @hrafn You can do unlimited nested mapslike this way ` map(function($user){ return [ 'id' => $user->id, 'son' => $user->sons()->get()->map(function($son) { return [ ... ]} ]);`

Answer (score 0):

On the model get the keys you need and then with [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map) change the key `reference` to `parent`, on that check if is null the `reference` to put a 0 then encode the array for json with [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$array = Model::get(['id', 'name', 'reference'])
   ->map(function($model){
        return [
           'id' => $model->id,
           'name' => $model->name,
           'parent' => is_null($reference->reference)? 0 : $reference->reference,
        ];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Then just make a json with that array:

`echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: My main problem is how do I get the data from the database connected like this. I want to get all the users under the user because they are linked. So it's like a family tree.

Comment: @hrafn you want the Model classe? chech [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).